# Many friends in one story

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I have added new object type, action and story in developers facebook app page.
Everything is fine, adding new object works, publishing story also works.

But I need story where there is more than one person (more than me), eg. after publishing it should write "Poul ,Maciek and 3 other persons went to music shop via App". How to accomplish it?

I have tried to create one object, than publish it as a story on two different accounts, but didn't work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This kind of aggregation is managed by Facebook algorithms, but you can tag people in open graph action.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/guides/tagging/#people

Comment: Thanks for reply! Do you know how those algorithms works? Should I publish story with the same object to achieve this?

Comment: I think that same object with same action should be aggregated, but no one really knows how facebook works ;)